# Symfony2 include form on error page (404)

Tags: forms, symfony, error-handling, http-status-code-404, symfony-2.4

I created a custom error template

`app/Resources/TwigBundle/views/Exception/error404.html.twig`

and

`app/Resources/TwigBundle/views/Exception/exception_full.html.twig`

for development to change the layout to what ever I want to. This works fine. But, as soon as I add a form (e.g. my search or a contact form) using

`{{ include ('MyCoreBundle:Default/forms:myCustomForm.html.twig' ) }}`

or enter the code directly it shows a `ResourceNotFoundException` and a `NotFoundHttpException` instead of the 404 page.

Is there any way to display a form on the error templates?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about using an [embedded controller](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#embedding-controllers)?

Here's the short example taken from Symfony's documentation page.

You have a controller that returns and renders some output:

```
// src/Acme/ArticleBundle/Controller/ArticleController.php
class ArticleController extends Controller
{
    public function recentArticlesAction($max = 3)
    {
        // make a database call or other logic
        // to get the "$max" most recent articles
        $articles = ...;

        return $this->render(
            'AcmeArticleBundle:Article:recentList.html.twig',
            array('articles' => $articles)
        );
    }
}
```

In this example, it renders a view:

```
{# src/Acme/ArticleBundle/Resources/views/Article/recentList.html.twig #}
{% for article in articles %}
    <a href="/article/{{ article.slug }}">
        {{ article.title }}
    </a>
{% endfor %}
```

and in the view you'd like to embed controller's action:

```
{# app/Resources/views/base.html.twig #}

{# ... #}
<div id="sidebar">
    {{ render(controller('AcmeArticleBundle:Article:recentArticles', {
        'max': 3
    })) }}
</div>
```

The docs page also says that you should use and embedded controllers when you need data that you don't have access to in a template. From my point of view, it's perfect for creating widgets, some statistics and so on.

Hope this helps.

**Edit**

To make this answer more accurate to your issue, here's the solution I'd use:

1. You'll need a controller, let's call it `SearchController`
2. In the controller's `renderForm()` method, you need to create a form and pass it to the view
3. Form's action attribute should point to `resultAction()` method where you can fetch the results from your data storage and display result to the end user.